# JavaScript: How to determine a variable's scope?

Tags: javascript, scope, local-variables

If I do:

```
var i = j = 0;
```

1. Is `j` a local variable?
2. Prove it.

Comment: It depends on whether `j` was declared earlier in the environment `:P`. Since the statement is evaluated as `var i = (j = 0);` it should be clear that the `var` keyword does not apply to `j`.

Answer (score 6):

After hoisting, your code looks like:

```
var i;
j = 0;
i = j;
```

Therefore `i` is a local variable, but `j` is not.

Answer (score 2):

`j` would be a global variable, or get assigned to a variable in an out scope:

```
(function() { var i = j = 0;  })()

// i is undefined
// j is 0


var i = 42;
var j = 1;

(function() { var i = j = 0;  })()

// i remains 42
// j is 0
```

Answer (score 2):

For fun, here is another "proof":

```
(function() {"use strict"; var i = j = 0;}());
// throws "ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable j"
```

[*(Read more about strict mode)*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode)

Answer (score 1):

Since the declaration of `j` isn't in the same declaration expression as `i`, the variable is either created in the outer scope or, if it exists there it will overwrite the value in the outer scope.

The reason why `i` is now global is because of **variable hoisting**. You can break this down like this:

1) `var i`

2) `j`, which now declares `j` in the current scope, which is the containing scope since the expression is not bound to the current context because it's not using `var`.

3) `= 0`, which now assigns `j` to `0`, and subsequently assigns `j` to `i`.

Proof?

[image]

Comment: That was my suspicion, but how can it be proved programmatically?

Comment: @MattDiPasquale Compare result of `typeof` with `'undefined'`?

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){
    var i = j = 0;
})();

try{
    alert(i);   
}catch(e){
    alert(e);  
}

alert(j);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kDGM3/1/

Not particularly proof...nor would I use an exception in a normal program flow unless it was indeed an exceptional case. But it does demonstrate the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
function test(a){
    var i=j=0;
    return i;
};
test(100);
alert(j);
alert(i);
```

Comment: please do explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

check if it's on the `window` object `alert(window.j)` if it alerts it's value then it's global if not it's local (if it's not in a function when using the `var` keyword then it's global and without `var` then it's global no matter were you define it. so j and i are both global). example:

```
var i = j = 0;

 function x(){
   var r = 100;
    alert(r); 
 }
  alert(window.i); //will alert 0.
  alert(window.j); //will alert 0.
  x(); // will alert 100.
  alert(window.r); //will alert undefined.
```

or you can use `hasOwnProperty` like so `alert(window.hasOwnProperty("i"))` which returns a boolean value.

by the way, trying to test this using jsfiddle will make `i` return `undefined` (might have something to do with the way jsfiddle protects it's own global namespace) so you'll need a blank html page to test this